# SQL Grouping Running Count on Distinct over multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

Perhaps a performance issue, or it is wrong.

TabelA:

```
StudentID | Date  
----------|------  
1         | 20140101  
1         | 20140102  
1         | 20170103  
2         | 20140101  
2         | 20170103  
3         | 20140101  
3         | 20170103  
3         | 20170104
```

(primary key for tableA is: (studentID,Date)

```
TableB:  
StudentID|Date     |Class   | Warning | Instructor  
---------|---------|--------|---------|-----------  
1        |20140101 |History |Tardy    | Mr.H  
1        |20140101 |History |Homework | Mr.H  
1        |20140101 |Biology |Tardy    | Mr.B 
1        |20140102 |Biology |Homework | Mr.B   
1        |20140102 |History |Tardy    | Mr.H  
2        |20140101 |Math    |Test     | Mr.M 
2        |20140101 |Art     |Test     | Mr.A 
3        |20140101 |History |Tardy    | Mr.H  
3        |20170103 |History |Tardy    | Mr.H
```

Hopefully, this is enough data.
Goal: For each StudentId and date in tableA, get count of distinct (class,warning,instructor) up until the designated date in TableA.

Result expected:

```
StudentID | Date    | Count  
----------|---------|--------  
1         |20140101 |3        
1         |20140102 |4       
1         |20170103 |4  
2         |20140101 |2  
2         |20170103 |2        
3         |20140101 |1         
3         |20170103 |1  
3         |20170104 |1
```

Here is what I have:

```
select A.studentID, A.date, count(1)
from TableA A
cross apply (select distinct B.class,B.warning,B.instructor
             from TableB B
             where A.studentID = B.studentID
               and B.date <= A.date) Z
group by A.studentID, A.date
order by A.studentID, A.date
```

Is there a better/alternative way to achieve this result for large data sets?
Problem: I can't get the final result set for large data set (1 million rows).  It just keeps running.

Thanks!

Solution:
Removed "order by" clause
TableB already had an index for (date, studentID) and
I Added another index on Table B for (studentId,date).
Time difference: Before: > 15 mins Now: < 30 seconds

Comment: Why you need table A at all? it's ambiguous

Comment: Not all dates are in TableB.  In other words, there are dates in TableA that are not in TableB.  This can be seen in the result set for date 20170103.  TableA is a master table covering almost all days.

Comment: How this is 4? as per your example? 1         |20140102 |4

Comment: 3 from 20140101 and 1 from 20140102.  There is one that is in both 20140101 and 20140102, so it only counts as one (per the distinct).

Comment: 2 for 1| 20140102 right....          below records     1        |20140102 |Biology |Homework | Mr.B   -------------------------------
1        |20140102 |History |Tardy    | Mr.H

Comment: How is 1... for last three records?

Comment: You are taking ALL unique records amongst the 3 columns (class, warning, instructor) AS OF 20140101.   And then again as of 20140102 (here you include all record from 20140101 and 20140102, then determine uniqueness across the 3 columns).

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [inner join vs cross apply](https://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/). As tableB is self sufficient, I would use a join instead of a cross apply.

```
select
    A.studentID,
    A.date,
    isnull(B.record_count,0)
from TableA A
left join (
    select
        studentID,
        date,
        count(*) as [record_count]
    from TableB
    group by
        studentID,
        date) B
    on A.studentID = b.studentID
    and A.date >= B.date
group by
    A.studentID,
    A.date
order by
    A.studentID,
    A.date
```

If you still experience performance problems, I would examine your execution plan for potential missing indexes on TableB

Comment: Working on going through the index as it will definitely  help.  Also, removing the "order by" clause helps a lot. Thanks will get back after testing.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It was an index issue.  Solution added above.

Comment: Also, this answer doesn't account for distinct, and therefore, will not produce the same result.

Comment: The group by clause should return distinct results.